# How to formulate the braiding of instanton?

Tags: symmetry, ising-model, topological-order, instantons

I'm reading the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.08835, after imposing the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on-site symmetry, in the $J=0$ symmetric phase of the 1d Ising chain, the topological sectors of operators form the category $\mathcal{Z}_1(\text{Rep}(\mathbb{Z}_2))$. But I can't understand how the operators (or instanton, or $0$d topological defect) braid with each other, how is the braiding process realized by just multiplicating the operators?

[image]

Comment: Because $m$ only contains $X$ operators. To find the other $X$ to annihilate $m$ with, you have to commute $m$ past $Z$ which is the braiding.